# How to leave only Local Address and PID columns and get rid of its headings while using netstat?

Tags: netstat

I have such view of `netstat -ntlp`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 10.2.7.2:9100           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1190/node_exporter
```

How to get rid of external columns and its names by `netstat` functionality:

```
10.2.7.2:9100      1190/node_exporter
```

?

Comment: Does `netstat -ntlp | awk '/:/{print $4 " " $7}'` work for you? You might also want to use `ss` since `netstat` has been deprecated.